# Access Angularjs elements in browser console like scope or directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

How can you access the following Angularjs items in the browser?

$scope, 
Controller, 
Directive, 
$scope.function

Comment: It's ok to down vote.  It's also ok to leave a comment as to why the down vote, so things can be corrected and/or better explained...Let's improve together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Info:** https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

**Note:** If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite."

**

### Just use jquery or jqLite!!!

**

If you don't use jquery, but only Angularjs don't worry. You already have an abbreviated version of jquery wrapped up in your Angularjs file.

Right click on any item in the DOM in the browser
(for this example, I'm using Google Chrome Version 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit))

Open the console tab and type this in -

```
angular.element($0)
```

you should get the item back like this

```
[<my-directive></my-directive>]
```

Now try

```
angular.element($0).scope()
```

You will get the scope object with all it's goodies. Let's say it's the controllers scope.
Then you can influence it directly in the browser.  In this examples scope, there are userRoles.  Let's change the value in the browser...

```
angular.element($0).scope().userRole
```

Says it's "guest" so let's change it to "bananas"

```
angular.element($0).scope().userRole = 'bananas'
```

Now says it's 'bananas'

This is certainly useful to view what variable values are in the DOM, however if you want to change something and see the results you have to manipulate something in the DOM to see the changes. For example...

```
<div ng-show="butter">HELLO</div>
```

If you change the variable butter from it's loaded state, let's say it loaded true and is visible in the DOM and you change it to false

```
angular.element($0).$parent.butter = false
```

The change will not be visible in the current DOM without manipulating something in the DOM first. In this example, the div should disappear, but will not.  After I set ng-show butter to false, I need to click on something in the DOM to get the DOM to refresh it's state based on the changed value.

Something else...

$0 represents the item you have highlighted in your elements tab.  If you do this...

```
angular.element($1)
```

it will return something as well as trying

```
angular.element($2)
```

however it ends there and only returns [] with every new increment > than $2.
If anyone knows what this means please provide some info.

Of course, you can access everything in the DOM using ID, element, or class as well like so...

```
angular.element('#myDivId')
<div id="myDiv">
```

or

```
angular.element('#myDivId p a')
<div id="myDiv">
  <p>hello</p>
    <a href=''...></a>
```

There are more methods and features in the "Info" link above, like how to get the controller name. Check it out, and always remember... "have fun doing so."